# Any way to gitignore by file size?

Tags: git, gitignore

I fairly regularly attempt to add/commit a file above 100Mb accidentally, then scramble to try and remember how to backtrack these errors. Is there any way to place a safeguard that just has the effect of skipping `git add` for files that are too large?

Comment: You could add a pre-commit hook that rejects big files. Not exactly ignored, but maybe good enough for your problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+size

Answer (score 0):

You can typically gitignore only filenames, file patterns or folders - ignoring based on file sizes is not an available function afaik